# SQL Server CASE in WHERE with single condition but multiple returns

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause, sql-null

#### User Story

I need to select columns to check for empty values and the relationship in my selection is OR (e.g. where Cost IS NULL or PurchaseType IS NULL, or both are NULL).

#### Development Issues

My application has several queries which are conditional to the user making a selection. For example, if the selection fields are named @selection1 and @selection2 then my where clause looks like this:

```
select...
from...
where isActive=1 
and (@selection1=column or @selection1='')
and (@selection2=column or @selection2='')
```

This particular use case requires that I make OR relationships instead of AND which has added a wrinkle in my logic:

```
select..
from...
where isActive=1
and ((@selection1=column or @selection1='')
or (@selection2=column or @selection2=''))
```

if any one of the selections is empty (''='' in the latter half of each line), then the whole clause returns true and is skipped, returning all rows and ignoring the user's valid selection.

#### Code Sample

```
DECLARE @filter AS VARCHAR(100)=''
/**Options are empty
, Cost to show only where Cost IS NULL
, PurchaseType to show only where PurchaseType IS NULL
, PurchaseQuantity to show only where PurchaseQuantity IS NULL
, or any combination of these 3 values to show where ANY COLUMN in the combination IS NULL
so if the user selects 'Cost,PurchaseQuantity', then they want columns 1,2,3,4,7
and if the user selects 'PurchaseType,PurchaseQuantity', then they want columns 1,2,3,4,6.
**/

-- Create Sample Table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL
    Truncate TABLE #Product
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #Product (id INT, Cost DEC(8,2), PurchaseType VARCHAR(20), PurchaseQuantity INT, isActive bit);
INSERT INTO #Product 
 VALUES 
(1, NULL, NULL, NULL,1),
(2, 10.00, NULL, NULL,0),
(3, NULL, 'Each',NULL,1),
(4, NULL, NULL, 100,1),
(5, 5.50, 'Box',1,0),
(6, 142.00, NULL, 12,1),
(7, NULL, 'Pkg',50,1)

-- Select values from Sample Table
-- Works great for single @filter values, but fails for multiple
--SELECT id,Cost,PurchaseType,PurchaseQuantity FROM #Product
--WHERE
--  CASE WHEN @filter = 'Cost' THEN Cost
--      ELSE 
--      CASE WHEN @filter='PurchaseType' THEN PurchaseType
--      ELSE    
--      CASE WHEN @filter='PurchaseQuantity' THEN PurchaseQuantity
--      ELSE    
--      CASE WHEN @filter='Cost,PurchaseType' THEN COALESCE(Cost,PurchaseType)
--      --CASE WHEN @filter='Cost,PurchaseType' THEN Cost or PurchaseType
--      --The above line expresses what I'm trying to do in pseudo, but doesn't work for resulting when Cost IS NULL or PurchaseType IS NULL
--      ELSE    
--      CASE WHEN @filter='Cost,PurchaseQuantity' THEN COALESCE(Cost,PurchaseQuantity)
--      ELSE    
--      CASE WHEN @filter='PurchaseQuantity,PurchaseType' THEN COALESCE(PurchaseQuantity,PurchaseType)
--      ELSE    
--      CASE WHEN @filter='Cost,PurchaseQuantity,PurchaseType' THEN COALESCE(Cost,PurchaseQuantity,PurchaseType)
--      END END END END END END END
--      IS NULL

select id,Cost,PurchaseType,PurchaseQuantity,isActive
    from #Product
    where isActive=1 
    and (@filter !='' and
    (
     (Cost is null and @filter like '%Cost%')
     or
     (PurchaseType is null and @filter like '%PurchaseType%')
     or
     (PurchaseQuantity is null and @filter like '%PurchaseQuantity%')
    ))
```

I've added @Stu's logic but the "isActive=1 and" and other logic in my production architecture mean that I get zero results if the user leaves the filter empty rather than ignoring the @Filter portion (which is what I want to see occur).

As noted in my code sample, I ultimately want to set up the where clause so that

- If the user selects nothing for @filter, then the WHERE is skipped
- If the user selects a single value for @filter, then the WHERE returns where that single column IS NULL
- If the user selects multiple values for @filter, then the WHERE returns where any of the @filter columns are NULL

I've spent a day and a half on this and I'm getting nowhere... Hoping I missed something simple and someone in the interwebs has a way to resolve this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This just a bad design, I am afraid. Don't go down this path. Pass parameters for each coln you might be filtering on instead and design a "catch&all"/"kitchen sink" query.

Comment: This is a mare of a design, what if you had 5 columns, or 10?!

Comment: Discussions about [kitchen sink example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: My 2 cents - don't give the user too much flexibility. The cost to providing that is significant over time and rarely do users actually use much of it. I find users generally only need a few options for searching and generally use an even smaller set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fathom how you came up with this arrangement, however does this work for you? Hard to be sure!

```
    select id,Cost,PurchaseType,PurchaseQuantity,isActive 
    from #Product
    where isActive=1 and
    (@Filter ='' or
    (
     (Cost is null and @filter like '%cost%')
     or
     (PurchaseType is null and @filter like '%PurchaseType%')
     or
     (PurchaseQuantity is null and @filter like '%PurchaseQuantity%')
    ))
```

Note that this will almost certainly result in a poorly performing query especially if the table is large - 1000s of rows.

It would be better to do 3 separate queries and `union` the results - that way the optimizer can utilize suitable indexes on each.

Comment: I updated my sample to include the requirement that ```@Filter``` can be empty and I need other pieces of the WHERE clause to function without it. Maybe you could give it another go??